# All Endpoint Instances subscribe and handle event

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

I have a notification service that handles events and publishes them to clients using various technologies, such as SignalR. I want **every** instance of my notification service to pick up and handle these events. However, NServiceBus only allows any one instance of my notification service endpoint to pick up the event, and the other instances never get it.

My current workaround for this is to create a separate named endpoint for each instance of my notification service (the name has the server host name added to it), but then I have to make sure I unsubscribe from the event when the instance goes down or is moved to another server.

Is there a better way to do this? It would be nice if I could configure NServiceBus to create a separate incoming queue for each endpoint instance in this case, but I can't figure out how to do that, or even if NServiceBus supports such a use case.

Comment: Are all of the instances exactly the same, or do they have different capabilities e.g. each supports a given technology?

Comment: @Bob.Langley All endpoint instances are the same logical endpoint, and the exact same bits.

Comment: Which version of NServiceBus are you using?

Comment: @Bob.Langley 6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. NServiceBus does not support such a case. Subscribers are always treated as logical endpoints, so individualized queues would not be used even if they were available.

Differentiating the instances by modifying the endpoint name is the most straightforward way to achieve what you want.

Changing your differentiator to a controllable runtime value, for instance an environment variable, would at least alleviate the need to unsubscribe when an instance is moved.

Also, if you want to review the scenario in more detail please don't hesitate to reach out to us directly, we might have other approaches to suggest. Just open a support ticket.